# Prove the correctness of Tarjan's off-line least-common-ancestors algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis

Tarjan's off-line least-common-ancestors algorithm is given as follows:

> LCA($u$)
>
> 1. Make-Set($u$)
> 2. Find-Set($u$).$ancestor$ = $u$
> 3. for each child $v$ of $u$ in $T$
> 4. $\quad$ LCA($v$)
> 5. $\quad$ Union($u$,$v$)
> 6. $\quad$ Find-Set($u$).$ancestor$ $= u$
> 7. $u.color = $ BLACK
> 8. for each node $v$ such that $\{u, v\} \in P$
> 9. $\quad$ if $v.color == $ BLACK
> 10. $\quad \quad$ print "The least common ancestor of" u "and" v "is" Find-Set($v$).$ancestor$

Note that we are given a rooted tree $T$ and an arbitrary set $P = \{\{u,v\}\}$ of unordered pairs of nodes in $T$, and we want to determine the least common ancestor of each pair in $P$.  To solve the off-line least-common ancestors problem, the above procedure performs a tree walk of $T$ with the initial call
LCA($T.root$).  Assume that each node is colored WHITE prior to the walk.

Given this, prove that LCA (correctly) prints the least common ancestor of $u$ and $v$ for each pair $\{u,v\} \in P$.

I'm thinking I'd need to prove two cases 1. w.l.o.g. $v \in T_u$ and 2. $v \notin T_u$ and $u \notin T_v$, where $T_u$ and $T_v$ are subtrees of $T$ rooted at $u$ and $v$, respectively.